# Cryptic crossword clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

Machiavellian anagram of an orchestra section (?)

(I left the number of letters in the word as unspecified so as to increase the level of difficulty.)

Comment: It's a single word or multiple words?

Comment: @wildBillMunson You are correct Sir. Nicely done.

Comment: I've downvoted for two reasons: the definition doesn't properly define the word (we're just supposed to *discard* "iavellian", then interpret it as an adjective?), and the anagram is indirect (and clued by "anagram").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is

> SUPERSONIC

which is an anagram of

> PERCUSSION

It is Machiavellian because

> Supersonic speeds are measured with MACH numbers.

Comment: The definition is in the cryptic clue.

Comment: Apologies for that. I don't quite get the def. part.

Comment: I don't know. That doesn't work for me. The gimmick here is that Machiavellian (which means scheming, plotting) can be abbreviated to just Mach and _that_ in turn can mean having a Mach number greater than 1 or travelling faster than sound? That's a very sloppy and unsatisfying clue, in my opinion.

Comment: Nice anagramming! @user33336

Comment: @wildBillMunson Just curious: did you use a computer program to fiqure out the possible anagrams?

Comment: Nope the word SUPER jumped out at me right away. I'm a huge scrabble enthusiast, so anagrams are sort of my thing... :)